# saving ArrayList in the bundle savedInstanceState

Tags: android

the ArrayList is defined on class level.
these are my savedInstance methods:

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putStringArrayList("savedList", list);
}


@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    list=savedInstanceState.getStringArrayList("savedList");
}
```

but still, when i change orientation the ArrayList is blank

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4967491/1001401
Try to get your ArrayList in onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) from savedInstanceState

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `onRestoreInstanceState()` to restore state, its called after `onStart()` so you update your list with the saved state after you define your adapter. Your best option is to restore the list in `onCreate()` the same way you do it on `onRestoreInstanceState()`. You can also redefine the adapter or call `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Answer (score 3):

```
TextView textviewname;
String textname;

 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);   
          setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       //declare the ui like this
    textviewname = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textviewid);
       if(savedInstanceState==null){
       //the first time the activity was created
       //do the normal flow of the code
       //Example:getting the intent data for(savedList)or processing it
       Intent i = getIntent();
       textname = i.getStringExtra("savetext");
      //or textname="name_data";
       }else{
       //this is called when orientation change occur
       //get the savedata
        list=savedInstanceState.getStringArrayList("savedList");
        textname=savedInstanceState.getString("savetext");
       }

       textviewname.setText(textname);

}   
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    //saving data when orientation change trigger
    //saving  data before ondestroy happens
//onSaveInstanceState is called before going to another activity or orientation change
    outState.putStringArrayList("savedList", list);
    outState.putString("savetext", textname);
    //all imnportant data saved and can be restored
}


@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    //this is  only called after ondestroy-> oncreate occur
    list=savedInstanceState.getStringArrayList("savedList");
    textname=savedInstanceState.getString("savetext");
    //oncreate->onSaveInstanceState->ondestroy->oncreate->onRestoreInstanceState
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use

```
list.addAll(savedInstanceState.getStringArrayList("savedList"));
```

instead

```
list=savedInstanceState.getStringArrayList("savedList");
```